# jQuery .click won't trigger for user selection events spanning multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function (still in development) that needs to capture user selected text in a div (not text areas and input boxes so `.select` won't work.). Using `.click` and selection and range objects works great when the selection is contained within a single element in that div but fails to trigger if the user selection spans multiple elements within the div (like multiple p's).

```
    $('.relevantDivClass').click(function(){
        console.log('Got here');
        SelObj = window.getSelection();
        Range = SelObj.getRangeAt(0);
        if (SelObj.anchorNode == SelObj.focusNode){
            console.log('executing same node branch');
            string = SelObj.toString();
            console.log(string)
        }
        else{
            console.log('executing multiple node branch');
            //code...
        }
    });
```

Any ideas on how to get that event to trigger in that situation? It's still within the `relevantDivClass` so I'm confused as to why the `.click` won't trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.mouseup()` instead of `.click()`. When highlighting text across multiple paragraphs, the 'mouseup' event is not triggered on the same element that 'mousedown' was triggered on -- which is the definition of the 'click' event. `.click()` works for single paragraphs because you trigger both 'mousedown' and 'mouseup' on the `<p>` element, and it bubbles up to its parent, the `<div>`.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcbHC/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.relevantDivClass').mouseup( function() {
        alert('Got here');
        SelObj = window.getSelection();
        Range = SelObj.getRangeAt(0);
        if (SelObj.anchorNode == SelObj.focusNode){
            alert('executing same node branch');
            string = SelObj.toString();
            alert(string)
        }
        else{
            alert('executing multiple node branch');
            //code...
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help =). If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (there's a little check mark at the side you can press).

Comment: Yeah thanks for that I didn't even know how to accept. I kept trying to upvote, but it wouldn't accept due to my low score.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully using the lastest jQuery version, use this instead:

`$(".relevantDivClass").on("click", function() { /* code */ });`

Comment: Why should that make any difference? `.click` calls `.on` internally.

Comment: It doesn't... `.click()` is a shortcut for `.on('click')` - http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: `.click` wasn't working for me using the latest version, and switching to this worked.

Comment: As I said, it wasn't working for me. I even made sure I had my `.click` right! It wouldn't work, but this did. It just did.

Comment: Did not work for me, I'm using 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

So I don't think most recent jquery would be an issue. This is within a contenteditable div too, so could that be what's messing this up?

Comment: I believe you, but I think it was coincidence or what not. `.on('click', ...` and `.click` are **equivalent** (see [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/event.js#L1052)). Have a look at the source code. If one does not work, the other won't either. Unless you provide an example where `.click` works differently than `.on('click', ...)`, my opinion stands and your answer is not useful. Source code is more worth than a thousand words. I assume your problem was somewhere else (maybe a typo).